# Retrieving a youtube playlist without asking the user for login

Tags: ios, youtube-api, google-api-objc-client

is it possible to retrieve a public youtube playlist with the google-api-objectivec-client without asking the user to login in order to perform the OAuth 2.0 authentication?

I'm working on an app which should retrieve a playlist from youtube and play related videos, but I cannot and don't want to ask the user to login.

In the examples of google-api-objectivec-client (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FExamples%2FYouTubeSample) I'm not able to achieve it without OAuth 2.0 authentication.

Thanks,
DAN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you don't need OAuth2 login for that. You can simply do it by setting your API key instead.

It's a playlistItems->list request.

Here's demonstration in api explorer: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet&playlistId=PLjFEz-E0UPUxw3lFpnfV1dDA7OE7YIFRj&_h=2&

Instead of setting the authorizer of the service to OAuth2 login like in

> youtubeservice.authorizer = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch
>   authForGoogleFromKeychain.....

set it's API key to your API key from cloud console in Public API access.

> youtubeService.APIKey = xxxxxx

Comment: Yes I do agree but how would you achieve it with the google-api-objectivec-client? 'executeQuery' on an GTLServiceYouTube passing a GTLQueryYouTube instance without OAuth I get an authorization error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Done! I get this error: "com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain" - "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
But in the Google Console, "YouTube Data API v3" is enabled" (the switch is set to on).

Comment: The problem seems to be the bundle id associated to the api key: even if it is correct, if I delete it in the developer console, it works... this is very strange

Comment: You are right, just remove bundle id for now. This issue is reported internally. You can track it through public issue tracker.
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5770